# iframe src is not changing when I click back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, src

```
 <iframe id ="iframeA" name="iframeA" src="./friendList.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

I have an iframe tag like this.. and When the parent frame is loaded I add some tags in this iframe body. However when I change iframe src to './letterList.html' using jquery then letterList.html will be loaded correctly and then when I click back button, iframe src is not change to original './friendList.html'(even the focus was in the iframe) , But the content in iframe was './friendList.html' 's content. only src was not changed. and of course the tags that I added in iframe body was gone. I understand that tags were gone, but I can't understand why src is not changed but the contents in iframe is the original iframes'content.
Anybody can help me?.....

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how you mean 'why'. This is not error, this is [specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-src) behaviour (look at the note right before `name` attribute description). This was probably done because iframes sometimes should be unable to interact with parent document at all.
However, if you want to handle that, you might for example catch `onbeforeunload` event in iframe and reset its `src`.